# Batch Scripting Search .Txt files

Tags: batch-file

I have 1 TB of .txt files with metadata content. The first column indicates the name of the file. The goal is to get all .txt files inside the directory `C:\Textfiles\Docs` and append the new file path inside every .txt file, like this `D:\Docs\textfile1.txt` with its filename.

Is there way to create a batch script to fulfil this?

Original .txt file (location drive C:

```
filename | data1 | data2 | data3
```

Output (and pastes in new location in drive D:

```
D:\Docs\filename | data1 | data2 | data3
```

Here is my attempt:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    set found=false
    If "!found! " == "false" (
      COPY "D:\Docs\" > file1.txt Set found =true
 )
)
```

Comment: I have added the code to your question. I noticed that you have a space in your first variable in the `if` statement, why is that? this part `"!found! "`. You should also double quote when you set variables `set "found=false"`

Comment: There are _a lot_ of missed details, but the most important one is this; have each file _just one line_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty incomplete, but anyway here it is a Batch file that *may* work:

```
@echo off

cd "C:\Textfiles\Docs"
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
   (for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=|" %%a in ("%%f") do (
      echo D:\Docs\%%f ^|%%b
   )) > "D:\Docs\%%f"
)
```

Please, do NOT reply a comment that just indicate: "this code don't work". Instead, review what is the detail in your real data that you don't posted that cause that the output be wrong and *carefully* describe what changes would be needed in the code in order to fix it... **`:/`**